# Xpath, fetching table with text and images in Google sheets

Tags: xpath, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, xpath-2.0, xpath-1.0

I'm trying to parse this table into Google Sheets: https://exvius.gamepedia.com/Chaining/Bolting_Strike
And getting the title text from where there are images.

I can't figure out how to get the text from the full table, as well as `img/@alt` in cases where it's available. I can get the table with

`=IMPORTXML("https://exvius.gamepedia.com/Chaining/Bolting_Strike","//table[@class='wikitable']/tbody/tr[position()>=3]")`

And only the image texts

`=IMPORTXML("https://exvius.gamepedia.com/Chaining/Bolting_Strike","//table[@class='wikitable']/tbody/tr[position()>=3]/td/a/img/@alt")`

But I can't seem to do both, is that a limitation of Google Sheets IMPORTXML?

I've tried with OR and other bool operators with no luck. Tried with axes but that was also a no go for me.

Comment: I have 2 questions for your question. 1. When I saw the HTML data, I noticed that the 1st rows have the rows merged with the several rows, and the number of `<td></td>` is different for each row. In this case, when the values retrieved with your 1st formula, it's off by one column. How about this? 2. By this, also, when your 2nd formula is used, it's off by several rows for the values retrieved with the 1st formula. How about this?

Comment: Yeah, this stumped me to, i wasn't sure how to handle it..

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now I noticed that your issue was resolved. I'm glad for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I propose something like this :

[image: GP]

[Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aMKv89Cfr1PxV9IDV4pFLYhSiSDTGyicDsP189b2ZPI/edit?usp=sharing)

Description:

In `B1` we have the url of the webpage.
In `B3` we have  the following formula to import the first part of the table :

```
=QUERY(IMPORTHTML(B1;"table";1);"select Col1,Col2,Col3 OFFSET 2";0)
```

Columns `L` to `O` contain the following formulas to get the element names and the ability names (which will be used as a key in a `VLOOKUP` step). 4 formulas because an ability could have 2 element names. In `L3`,`M3`,`N3`,`03` we have :

```
=IMPORTXML(B1;"//td/a[1]/img[@srcset]/ancestor::td[1]/preceding::a[1][@title]")
=IMPORTXML(B1;"//td/a[1]/img[@srcset]/@alt")
=IMPORTXML(B1;"//td/a[2]/img[@srcset]/ancestor::td[1]/preceding::a[1][@title]")
=IMPORTXML(B1;"//td/a[2]/img[@srcset]/@alt")
```

Formula in `E4` is a one liner where the results of 2 `VLOOKUP` are merged  together. We use `VLOOKUP` to pair each ability name with an element.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C4:INDIRECT("C"&COUNTA(C:C)+2);L:M;2;FALSE);"")&"|"&ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C4:INDIRECT("C"&COUNTA(C:C)+2);N:O;2;FALSE);"")));"^\||\|$";""))
```

To finish, in `H3` we have the last part of the table :

```
=QUERY(IMPORTHTML(B1;"table";1);"select Col5,Col6 OFFSET 2";0)
```

The rest (colours, borders,..) is standard and conditionnal formatting.

Side note : I'm based in Europe so you might have to change `;` with `,` in the formulas.

Comment: Very clean solution, thank you very much!

I never thought of breaking up the table with using both IMPORTHTML and IMPORTXML.

Comment: Glad I could help. I've updated the post and the sheet with a more elegant solution for column E (no more 2 masked columns and `TEXTJOIN`).

Comment: Ah, that looks nice, I'll use that in my sheet, thanks again!